# subtract two string using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have one problem , i'm trying to remove fake data from the text where i add it. i have two python code ; one python code in server side will fetch the data from mysql and add some fake data into that text as shown below in the code . the variable **fak** will have randomly fake data from the library **fake.name()** the value is **maria mark** ,after that will add this fake data into the data was selected from mysql **name= row[1]+fak** ; the value of **row[1]** is **john** so its will be **john maria mark**

```
fak=fake.name()
  name= row[1]+fak
  print(name)
```

> > > > > john maria mark

now in client side i want the original data only without fake data, i have import the server file and call the varible **fak** , the xxc2 its a variable which hold the data  **john maria mark**.

```
import server as dcr
     fakw=dcr.fak             
        for i,j in zip(xxc2,fakw):
            if (i != j):
                print (i)


i >>>>its suppose to give me john only>> but its not
```

I hope my query is clear .thx

Comment: Tryed to edit - failed - rolled back. Please make this a [mcve]- it is unclear what you do.

Comment: zipping two strings will mix its characters up to the shorter lenght: `zip('aaa' , 'bbbbb' )` => `('a','b'),('a','b'),('a','b')`  ... printing one letter at a time will lead to one letter a line output ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def remove_fake(server_input, fake):
  if server_input.endswith(fake):
    return server_input[:-len(fake)]
  return server_input

somestring = remove_fake('john maria mark', ' maria mark')
print(somestring)
```

it gives:

> > john

does it helped?

Comment: Thank you , but actually the fake data will be generating randomly every time. i have N raw data in database , so everytime i request a query , fake data will be generated randomly ,and i cant define this in the code ( somestring = remove_fake('john maria mark', ' maria mark') )

Comment: So how can you differentiate the fake word out?

Comment: well sir, if you look to first code you will see that i add the fake data into the original data and , before i add i will add dot (.) in between that can be differentiate?

Comment: you are not clear. Please clarify

Comment: Sorry sir, the variable name in first code server side will hold select data from database (john) and before i add the fake data that was generated automatically (maria mark) i will add dot .) in between  , its will be like john.maria mark. now in client side i want to remove the data was added after dot(.) how i can do it? i hope its clear now

Comment: `somestring .split('.')[0]` ?

Comment: thx u . done  its work

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please vote up and mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information